# Rails 4 Create Related Object After Save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have two models with the [fields]:

Order [:date]
Delivery Slot [:day]

Order `belongs_to :delivery_slot`

When an order is created, I want a delivery slot to be created with the `:day` set to the order `:date`.

So far I have created a new method `create_delivery_slots` in the Order controller that creates a Delivery Slot when the Order is created, but where I am stumped is, how do I get the Order `:date` in the Delivery Slot `:day` field?

```
#Create delivery slots if they dont already exist
def create_delivery_slots
  existingslots = []
  existingslots = DeliverySlot.all.select {|slot| slot.day == @order.date}
  if existingslots.empty?
    slot = DeliverySlot.new(:day => @order.date)
    slot.save!
  end
```

I have tried multiple approaches, but no luck. My gut tells me its something to do with strong parameters but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly of how you're set up but you'll probably want something like this:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_a :delivery_slot
  after_create => :create_delivery_slots
  .
  #other code stuffs
  .
  .
  private

  def create_delivery_slots
    existingslots = []
    existingslots = DeliverySlot.all.select {|slot| slot.day == self.date}
    if existingslots.empty?
      slot = DeliverySlot.new(:day => self.date)
      slot.save!
    end
  end
end
```

That's untested but it should be basically what you need.

Comment: Thanks Micah, that does create a new delivery slot record. However the new record is blank - the value of `:day` has not been set.

Comment: @blackfish64 then there's a good chance you're not setting the Order's date in time. Only thing I can think of that would make the DeliverySlot not have a date.

Comment: Also make sure you use `self.date` and not `@order.date`

Comment: thanks for your help but I still can't get it to work. I changed the callback to `before_create` as after your comment about the time, I thought this would work.

Comment: @blackfish64 not quite what i meant by time and in fact before_create will make the problem worse. Reset it to after_create and try setting the date manually. Instead of `self.date` set it to `Date.today`. If that works, then your Order object doesn't have a date assigned to it when this function is being called, meaning you're not initializing your Order properly.

Another option is that your `DeliverySlot.all...` bit is returning a non-empty array preventing you from ever reaching the slot creation. Might want to check on that too.

Comment: I feel very, very stupid... The button I was using to create the Order was `<%= button_to "Order", orders_path(:order => {:user_id => current_user, :menu_recipe_id => menu_recipe.id, :status => 'Draft' })%>` which is obviously not setting the date on the Order so no wonder is was blank!! I have changed it to `<%= button_to "Order", orders_path(:order => {:user_id => current_user, :menu_recipe_id => menu_recipe.id, :status => 'Draft', :date => Date.today })%>` and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Ahha! So I was right about the date not being set on the `Order`. Sweet deal. Don't worry about making that kinda mistake. We all do at times lol. Good luck on the rest of your project! And if you would like to mark this as an answer I would not be opposed at all. Internet points and all :D

Comment: Enjoy those internet points. Immediately on to my next issue.. a for loop that inadvertently generates a record for every half an hour since 01.01.2000... but I guess thats for another question!